# Incorrect result from CurrentRegion when used in a function called from a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA function to be called from a cell. In this function I need to use the CurrentRegion property but it returns an unexpected result.

The function:

```
Function GetVarRange() As String

    Dim rngRangeToLeft As Range, wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Application.Caller.Worksheet
    Set rngRangeToLeft = wks.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    GetVarRange = rngRangeToLeft.Address

End Function
```

The result I get in the cell is $A$1.

There are values in A1, and all around it, the CurrentRegion is actually A1:AD618 and this is the result I get when I access the property within the code editor (not in this function) and when I press ctrl+A when A1 is selected.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2):

**CurrentRegion** does not work correctly in *UDF()'s* called from worksheet cells.  I have also found problems with **FindNext** and **SpecialCells.**

Called from a *Sub*, it is a different story:

```
Function GetVarRange(rng) As String
    Dim rngRangeToLeft As Range, wks As Worksheet
    Set rngRangeToLeft = rng.CurrentRegion
    GetVarRange = rngRangeToLeft.Address
End Function

Sub MAIN()
MsgBox GetVarRange(Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

appears to work just fine.