# UDF Array resulting in #Value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF as detailed below.  When I step through the formula by calling it in a Sub and using a msgbox to return the result, I end up with the correct result.  So it appears to work fine.  however, when I use as a UDF in a cell of the worksheet, I get #VALUE as a result.  What am I missing?

```
Function ToolStatus(PartNumber As String, Model As String, Number As Integer) As String
Dim SearchSheet As Worksheet
Dim PN As Long
Dim MdlCol As Long
Dim Mdl As String
Dim Result As Long
Dim SearchArray As Variant
Dim PartCount As Long
Dim i As Long
Application.Volatile True
ToolStatus = ""
PartCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet2.Range("A:A"))
Select Case True
    Case Number < PartCount And Model = "1A"
        Set SearchSheet = Sheet2
        PN = 3
        MdlCol = 5
        Mdl = "1A"
        Result = 20
    Case Number < PartCount And Model = "1B"
        Set SearchSheet = Sheet2
        PN = 3
        MdlCol = 6
        Mdl = "1B"
        Result = 20
    Case Number < PartCount And Model = "1C"
        Set SearchSheet = Sheet2
        PN = 3
        MdlCol = 7
        Mdl = "1C"
        Result = 20
    Case Number >= PartCount And Model = "1A"
        Set SearchSheet = Sheet3
        PN = 2
        MdlCol = 18
        Mdl = "-1A"
        Result = 5
    Case Number >= PartCount And Model = "1B"
        Set SearchSheet = Sheet3
        PN = 2
        MdlCol = 19
        Mdl = "-1B"
        Result = 5
    Case Number >= PartCount And Model = "1C"
        Set SearchSheet = Sheet3
        PN = 2
        MdlCol = 20
        Mdl = "-1C"
        Result = 5
End Select

SearchArray = SearchSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

For i = LBound(SearchArray, 1) To UBound(SearchArray, 1)
    If SearchArray(i, PN) = PartNumber And SearchArray(i, MdlCol) = Mdl Then
        ToolStatus = SearchArray(i, Result)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Can you add the all important first line please.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  I've updated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065057/incorrect-result-from-currentregion-when-used-in-a-function-called-from-a-cell... I don't think `CurrentRegion` works well in UDFs.

Comment: if searchSheet be nothing that error will be shown. set For-Next loop inside a If condition: `If Not searchSheet Is Nothing Then ....`

Answer (score 0):

As @BigBen pointed out, the `.CurrentRegion` was the issue.  I replaced `SearchArray = SearchSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion` with `SearchArray = SearchSheet.Range("A1:CD2000").Value` just to test and it worked.  SO I need to figure out how to make the range adjust, but now I know the issue was `CurretnRegion`.