# I cannot get the correct range (using currentRegion) by calling a vba function from a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Update 2: The solution is to get the range from the user within the function call

```
    Function findMatrixValue(RowHeader As Variant, _
                         ColHeader As Variant, _
                         rangeAsParam As Variant) _
                         As Variant

'=findMatrixValue($A$17;$D$1;"A1:E20")
'=findMatrixValue($A$17;$D$1; A1:E20)
'=findMatrixValue($A$17;$D$1;Table7[#All])

On Error GoTo Errorhandler:
 
       Dim myRange As range
       Dim mycellRow, mycellCol As range
       Dim errorMsg As String
       errorMsg = "Value not found in the given range, pls. proove your input parameter"
       
       'if any error occured, initially set
       findMatrixValue = errorMsg
            
            
        If (TypeName(rangeAsParam) = "String") Then
           Set myRange = range(rangeAsParam)
        End If
        If (TypeName(rangeAsParam) = "Range") Then
           Set myRange = rangeAsParam
        End If
        
'        Debug.Assert Not myRange Is Nothing
'        Debug.Assert TypeName(myRange) = "Range"
'        Debug.Assert RowHeader <> ""
'        Debug.Assert ColHeader <> ""
 
    If (Not myRange Is Nothing And TypeName(myRange) = "Range" And RowHeader <> "" And ColHeader <> "") Then
            
            'Find matrix coordinates
            Set mycellRow = myRange.find(RowHeader)
            Set mycellCol = myRange.find(ColHeader)
            
            If (Not mycellRow Is Nothing And Not mycellCol Is Nothing) Then
                       Debug.Print "Matrix Coordinates:" _
                            & "Found at Row:" & mycellRow.row _
                            & " and Column: " & mycellCol.Column
                    'set matrix coordinates
                    findMatrixValue = Cells(mycellRow.row, mycellCol.Column)
        End If
        End If

Errorhandler:
    If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
     End If
End Function
```

[Microsoft's documentation found....this confirms the comments below](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1)

I think the problem of "untraceable hidden connections" as mentioned by John is important to understand,
why some things are not working, this seems to be a good reason..

Update:

As many Functions seem not to work, I'm now trying to get the range within a Parameter:

```
 Function gettingTheRange(rangeAsParam As range) As Integer

   Dim myArr As Variant
   myArr = rangeAsParam.value 'The array is filled!

   'What is not working... as mentioned in the comments, is e.g.

   Dim res As range
   res = rangeAsParam.find("start")

   'All code after ".find" is being ignored

   gettingTheRange = 42

End Function
```

---

I'm using (for the first time) a function call of my own function written in VBA from within an Excel cell.

Question:
The testcall below from within VBA works fine, but calling "gettingTheRange"
from a cell has the problem, that the Range is not recognized, you can see that the array copied
from the range  only contains the value of the Cell.

The messageboxes are coming up and the testvalue is written correctly into the cell.
But what I really need is the Range, since in the function I want to build I want to find a String within a Range.
This is working in VBA already fine, but calling it from a cell causes the problem which I'm addressing here....

```
 Sub testcall()
    MsgBox gettingTheRange    
End Sub

Function gettingTheRange() As Integer
MsgBox "In the beginning"

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ListOfAllNames_ALL  'just adjust
Dim myArr As Variant
myArr = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
gettingTheRange = 5

MsgBox "At the end..."
```

End Function

Comment: [CurrentRegion doesn't work with UDFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065057/incorrect-result-from-currentregion-when-used-in-a-function-called-from-a-cell).

Comment: You need to pass the range as a parameter to the function

Comment: `CurrentRegion doesn't work with UDFs.` - many Range properties don't, [even `Text`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6470263/11683). And it's [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thiscell#remarks).

Comment: Side note, consider using `Debug.Print` statements instead of `MsgBox`; the output will go to the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G) without otherwise disrupting execution like a modal message box does.

Comment: Having a UDF depend on the current region would create untraceable dependencies between the values in the cell and the values in the current region. Excel's calculation engine wouldn't work properly with such hidden connections between cells.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you.. I have to consider a different approach...

Comment: @GSerg Thank you, I'm now trying to pass the Range as Parameter...

Comment: @CharlesWilliams: Thank you, I'm just trying it out...

This is working somehow, I'm getting the Array from the Range, given by the User as Parameter , but if I'm trying to get access to the Range itself, it seems to behave strange, all code written after the Access like rangeAsParam.find("start") is being ignored. so many things indeed are not working as mentioned before..

But

Function gettingTheRange(rangeAsParam As range) As Integer

    Dim myArr As Variant
    myArr = rangeAsParam.value

End Function

putting the Data into the Array and I can use this Data for a search...

Comment: @Chris Please put code into your question ([edit]) if you want to ask something and just leave a comment that you added something. Code in comments gets useless pretty easily.

Comment: UDFs are not as flexible as subs. A common workaround is to write a sub which sets the value of a cell and use a `Worksheet_Change` event handler to enforce the link between the value in that cell and other values in the sheet.