# VBA - Function rng.CurrentRegion bug?

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to understand the behaviour of a VBA-Function for the last few hours, but couldn't find a solution.

First, the Excel-Workbook contains an Excel-Worksheet called "Tabelle1" and there is also some content in cell A1 as well as in the range("A1:B2").
When I call procedure x() from within VBA, an 2D array will be assigned to variable arr.
Same happens, when I call procedure y(), even if it is declared as function.

Now when I call function f("Tabelle1") from within an Excel-Worksheet, it is assigning the value "A" to variable rng, so casting will throw an error as "A" is no array.
Normally this behavior happens, when the current region is empty, but it still has the same values.

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub x()

    Dim str As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim arr() As Variant

    str = "Tabelle1"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(str)

    Set rng = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arr = rng

End Sub


Public Sub y()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = f("Tabelle1")
End Sub


Public Function f(nameWs As String) As Variant()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandling

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim arr() As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(nameWs)

    Set rng = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arr = rng

    f = arr

Exit Function

ErrorHandling:
    MsgBox ("Error."), vbInformation
End Function
```

Can somebody please explain this to me, maybe I don't understand the field CurrentRegion, but there is not much documentation for it..

Comment: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66138873)