# Print array called from Excel cell (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure if I need a sub or a function here, but I need something that can:

1. Be called from a cell in Excel
2. Can print values into other cells in the same worksheet

For eg.

```
Function PrintDemo(CellRef As Range)
Set CellRef = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
Dim i as Integer

CellRef.Offset( , 5).Value = i
PrintDemo = 3
End Function
```

If I try to call this using =PrintDemo(D1) in an excel cell, hoping to print '123' 5 cells to the right, it just shows VALUE error. The function doesn't actually need to return anything, I made it hoping it would solve the error (it didn't). Nothing gets printed.

I haven't used VBA much (definitely not for printing) and I'm sure I'm missing something very fundamental in terms of how things are called. Please help me out.

**EDIT: Makes sense that I can't change other cells, can I store my result as an array somewhere and have a range of cells access its values one at a time?**

eg. outputArr=[1,2,3,4,5]

A2 -> =outputArr(0)

B2 -> =outputArr(1) and so on

It'll actually be 2D array but I don't think that should make much of a difference. The reason I need formulae everywhere is because this has to run in many places in the sheet, hence can't have any manual steps.

Comment: Except for some edge cases, you can't do this. UDFs called from a cell aren't meant to modify the worksheet. Also, [`CurrentRegion` doesn't work in a UDF called from a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065057/incorrect-result-from-currentregion-when-used-in-a-function-called-from-a-cell).

Comment: You can't change another cell using a UDF - `=SUM(A1:A5)` will only ever return a value to the cell it was typed into, you can't expect it to show the answer in cell B5 if the formula is in cell B1.

Comment: Look at the `Worksheet_Change` event. Using that event, your VBA can detect a change in one or more cells and run any code you want, including modifying any cells you want.

Comment: Please see edit, thanks